# Numpy split that returns an ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a method analogous to `numpy.split` that returns a `numpy.ndarray` instead of a `list`? Assuming that the array splits evenly is fine (to prevent jagged arrays).

For example:

```py
x = np.arange(9.0)
print(np.split(x, 3))
# [array([0.,  1.,  2.]), array([3.,  4.,  5.]), array([6.,  7.,  8.])]

print(np.???(x, 3))
# array([[0.,  1.,  2.], [3.,  4.,  5.], [6.,  7.,  8.]])
```

I'd rather not stack the list given from `np.split` together for performance reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you just want to [reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) the array:

```
numpy.reshape(x, (3, -1))
```

Here, `(3, -1)` means 3 rows and an inferred number of columns.